# Implementing flatten

Tags: haskell

I'm currently try to implement common functions on lists and I created the function '++' eg.

[11,22] ++ [4,2,8,1,7,12,4]

> [11,22,4,2,8,1,7,12,4]

as follows:

```
concatenate l t =  case l of
                     x:r -> x:concatenate r t
                     []  -> t
```

and this is working! no problems.

But now, I'm trying to write `flatten`;

```
 flatten[[11,22],[4,2,8,1,7,12,4]]
```

> [11,22,4,2,8,1,7,12,4]

But, I don't know how to do it, because, you have a list, containing n lists, with different sizes (the objective is to not use any standard functions). I tried eg.

```
concatenate l t =  case l of
                     x:r -> x:concatenate r t
                     []  -> t 

flatten l = flattenL l []
      where flattenL l t= case l of
              x:r -> flattenL (r (concatenate x t)) -- here x is a list, so that can't work
              []  -> t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close, just one line change,

`x:r -> flattenL r (concatenate x t)`

because `flattenL` needs 2 arguments and `r` is not a function.

Note that this does reverse the outer list order, eg.

`flatten [[1,2],[3,4,5]] = [3,4,5,1,2]`

To fix this, you could reverse the outer list before passing it to `flattenL`

`flatten l = flattenL (reverse l) []`

or, change the other line to,

`x:r -> concatenate x (flattenL r [])`

But this reveals that we're not really accumulating in the variable `t` at all! So the function simplifies to

```
flatten l = case l of 
  [] -> []
  l:ls -> l ++ flatten ls
```

aka

`flatten [] = []
flatten (l:ls) = l ++ flatten ls`

A fold would be a natural way to express it, I know you're not permitting yourself standard functions though. A list comprehension is also quite nice eg. `flatten ls = [x | l <- ls, x <- l]`.

Answer (score 0):

I will just add the final modification, but i go it, thank to Tayler
   finaly, i juste use my concatene fonction on my fonction on the final line:

```
concatene (l,t) =  case l of
                         x:r -> x:concatene (r,t)
                         []  -> t 
aplatir l = case l of 
  [] -> []
  x:r -> concatene (x,aplatir(r))
```

and can also declare it localy

```
aplatirF l = let concateneL (l,t) =  case l of
                     x:r -> x:concateneL (r,t)
                     []  -> t in
                     case l of 
                         [] -> []
                         x:r -> concateneL (x,aplatirF(r))
```

and everything working, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Consider this sequence of transitions:

```
flatten [[11,22],[4,2,8,1,7,12,4]] 
==> 11 : flatten [[22],[4,2,8,1,7,12,4]]
         ==> 22 : flatten [[],[4,2,8,1,7,12,4]]
                  ==> flatten [[4,2,8,1,7,12,4]]
                  ==> 4 : flatten [[2,8,1,7,12,4]]
                          ==> 2 : f [[8,1,7,12,4]]
                                  ==> .....
                                      .....
                                           ==> 4 : flatten [[]]
                                                   ==> flatten []
                                                   ==> []
```

Thus we see just a few laws here:

```
flatten ((x:xs):r) = x : flatten (xs:r)
flatten (   [] :r) = flatten r
flatten []         = []
```

Now all that's left is to put these laws into code.